# How long should the smell of silicone caulk last?

Tags: bathroom, ventilation, smell, caulk

I recaulked around my tub last night with 100% silicone caulk. It's now been a bit over 12 hours, so the caulk is set and I can get the tub wet (according to the instructions on the tube), but the bathroom still stinks of silicone.

The bathroom is pretty small, only about 6x10'. I don't know the CFM of the vent fan, but it has been running constantly for about 12 hours (from just after I finished the caulk job), and there's a pretty good gap under the door to allow fresh air to flow in.

**How long should I expect that smell to remain?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few days. Solvent will continue to escape the caulk from deeper in for a short while. After a week you probably won't detect it, but that depends on the nose.

Comment: Yes. It was a week before my wife stopped smelling ours. I stopped the next day.

Comment: My wife kept turning the bathroom fan off because she couldn't smell it, but I could. For me, the smell went away shortly after I posted the question.