# How long for CitriStrip fumes to dissipate

Tags: paint-removal

My wife was trying to get some paint off of the trim of the door in our kitchen, along with a bookcase nearby.  She used some CitriStrip to try to do this (about a cup's worth).  The CitriStrip worked well, and removed the paint, however, 2 1/2 days later, there is still the smell of CitriStrip coming from the area.  Our house is from 1914, so whatever may have been on the trim could have also been removed, along with some paint from the wall.  We left the windows open for a few hours to try to help remove the smell, but it's still there.

Does anyone know how long this will take to fully dissipate?  Are there safety concerns at this point (my wife said she felt dizzy while she was using it and thought she was just tired as she thought it was 'non-toxic', but it was likely the product)?

This is in the Midwest USA.

Comment: This can takes days or even to week to dissipate.  I used it outside my front door and could smell it in the house for 3 days.  Even if it falls to a level you cannot smell it, the vapor can still cause health issues.  Depending on your weather, you may want to go away for a couple of hours and leave all windows in the nearby area open with a box fan.    If you can get cross ventilation, you can clear it out faster.  Citristrip is 40% VOCs.   So that half of the cup will have vaporized.

Comment: @jeffatrackaid Thanks for your info, it was very helpful.....it's been almost a week and there is still some smell of the stuff, but we can't leave the windows open for too long at a time as it's below zero outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with all the air leaks in a house built in 1914, it's going to take a "while" for the fumes to dissipate.

As you'll note in [this Q&A](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/195292/how-long-should-the-smell-of-silicone-caulk-last) it took more than 12 hours (with a fan running most of the time) to dissipate the odor from silicone caulk. Depending on how sensitive your nose is, it could take 4 more hours, it could take 12 hours, it might be detectable for a week.

Unfortunately, there's no answer that's going to be 100% accurate for everyone because we all have different noses. It's going to take as long as it takes for you and your wife to not notice it any more.

That said, here in the Midwest USA, it's been rather cold the last few days and looks to remain so for the next few days, so your ventilation options are probably limited to running the bath & kitchen vent fans. Do so as much as possible/reasonable to pull "contaminated" air out of the house for speedier "smell-b-gone" action. ;)

Comment: This can takes days or even to week to dissipate.  I used it outside my front door and could smell it in the house for 3 days.  Even if it falls to a level you cannot smell it, the vapor can still cause health issues.

Comment: It's safer than turpentine, which is what it's usually a replacement for.